# Java memory model and concurrent read

Tags: java, multithreading, java-memory-model

```
class C {
  Object o;
  public void set(Object o){
     if(this.o == null){ 
        this.o = o;
     }
  }
  public Object get(){
     return o;
  }
}

C c = new C();
```

---

```
C c = new C();  

Thread#1
Object o1 = c.get(); // 1
Object o2 = c.get(); // 2

Thread#2
c.set(new Object());
```

Is it possible that `o2 == null && o1 != null`? 
    Why?

---

To make it clear what I mean I edited:

What if we have the following situation:

```
C c = new C(); // it is given at beginning 
1) Object o2 = c.o; // o2 is null. This operation was **reordered** before O `o1 = c.o. The JVM can do it because JMM allows do it. 
2) c.o = new Object()` //Thread #2 was executed 
3) O o1 = c.o // o1 is not null while o2 is.
```

Comment: I don't see how it's possible that `get()` ever returns anything except for `null`. `o` is never initialized and `set()` only modifies `o` if the argument is `null`

Comment: No, because c1 is retrieved before c2 and nothing can revert it to null in any other thread. However c2 could be non null while c1 is null

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible, despite the fact that you have a data race.

The data race is because your gets and sets around `o` aren't synchronized, which means there's no happens-before order with them. You could solve that either by having both methods be `synchronized`, or by making `o` volatile, or in a few other ways.

Absent synchronization, the JVM is allowed to reorder events as seen by other threads. From Thread1's perspective, you have the following events (with methods inlined for simplicity):

```
c.o = null; // initial value
o1 = c.o;
o2 = c.o;
c.o = new Object(); // from Thread2
```

Luckily for you, there are two restrictions that make this work:

1. The `c.c = null` happens-before all other actions (see [JLS 17.4.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5)).
2. From a given thread's perspective, actions that happen on that thread always happen in the same order they appear in the code (also JLS 17.4.5). So for Thread1, `o1 = c.o` happens-before `o2 = c.o`. (Thread2 would *not* have to see those reads in that order... but it never sees `o1` or `o2` at all, so there's no problem there.)

The first of those means that we can't take the `c.o = null` action and order it after `c.c = new Object()`. The second means that the reordering you mention at the bottom of your post is not allowed, from Thread1's perspective (and of course, Thread1 is the only thread that sees anything about o1 or o2).

Combining those two restrictions, we can see that if Thread1 ever sees `c.o` be non-null, then it will never see it revert back to null again. If o1 is non-null, then so must o2 be.

Note that this is pretty fickle. For instance, let's say that rather than only setting `c.o` once, Thread2 set it twice:

```
c.set("one");
c.set("two");
```

In that case, it *would* be possible to see `o1` be "two" while `o2` is "one". That's because the operations there are:

```
c.o = null; // initial value
o1 = c.o;
o2 = c.o;
c.c = "one"; // from Thread2
c.c = "two"; // from Thread2
```

The JVM can reorder the items from Thread2 however it sees fit, so long as they don't come before that `c.c = null`. In particular, this is valid:

```
c.o = null; // initial value
c.c = "two"; // from Thread2
o1 = c.o;
c.c = "one"; // from Thread2
o2 = c.o;
```

Removing the data race, by synchronizing the gets and sets to `o`, will fix that.

Comment: @Gilgamesz Interesting, you edited it but still didn't address the fact that `get()` is typed to return Object, but when you invoke it, you try to assign it to a C. Did I misinterpret that it should be `Object c1 = c.get()`?

Comment: @Gilgamesz I edited my answer to explain why it's still safe.

Comment: "Actions that happen on a thread always formally happen-before in the same order they appear in the code (also JLS 17.4.5), so o1 = c.o happens-before o2 = c.o."

You are not right. Please consider output for simple program:
int x, y;
**Thread #1**: x = 1; y = 1;  
**Thread #2**: print_without_sync(y); print_without_sync(x)

Comment: In your example, Thread 1 will see the write to x as happening before the write to y. The problem is that Thread 2 will _not_ necessarily see that order. I've clarified the language in my answer ("From a given thread's perspective...").

Comment: @Gilgamesz But in doing so, you taught me about JCStress -- I didn't know about that tool. Very cool stuff, thanks!